# How to query Salesforce Report with perl

Tags: perl, salesforce

I have a report in **Salesforce** that returns just the right information that is needed - (A long list of customer URLs and some more info columns for each url).

I also have a **Perl** script that goes over `csv` files and fills in missing information next to each URL.

***What I Need:***

1) For the **Perl** script to automatically query the report and get the most updated information before each run.

***What I Tried:***

1)`WWW::Salesforce::Report` [Cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~paixaop/WWW-Salesforce-Report-0.03/lib/WWW/Salesforce/Report.pm) Module - apparently is has unresolved login bugs for 5+ years and is no longer supported. ([Cpan bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=WWW-Salesforce-Report))

2)`WWW::Salesforce::Simple` [Cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/WWW-Salesforce/lib/WWW/Salesforce/Simple.pm) Module- This module allows me to run basic queries (`select Id from Account` - from examples) but I can't seem to find the correct query. I cant even find the names of objects in my Salesforce account.

What is the correct way to get info from the Salesforce report and in case it is option 2, how can I get the correct object names and/or export the query Salesforce uses for the report?